# Modify a form. Passing id as hidden value

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

Application: Spring MVC, Hibernate, JSP

Query: While modifying the form, I am passing pre-populated RECIPE object but id column is returned as NULL.

Recipe class has only 2 column - ID and NAME;

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/modify/{id}")
public String modifyRecipe(@PathVariable int id, Model model) {
    Recipe recipe = recipeService.findRecipe(id);
    model.addAttribute("recipe", recipe);

    return "recipes/modify";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "modify", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateRecipe(@Valid Recipe recip, Model model) {
    logger.info("From JSP [" + recipe + "]");

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "recipes/modify";
    }
    recipeServices.updateRecipe(recipe);
    return "redirect:/recipe/" + recipe.getId();
}
```

JSP Page

```
<body>
    <s:url value="/recipe/modify" var="recipe_modify" />
    <h2>
        Modify
        <c:out value="${fn:toUpperCase(recipe.name)}" />
    </h2>
    <sf:form modelAttribute="recipe" method="POST"
        action="${recipe_modify}">
        <fieldset>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th><sf:label path="name">Name of Recipe</sf:label></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><sf:input path="name" size="30" /> <br /> <sf:errors
                            path="name" cssClass="error"></sf:errors><br /></td>
                </tr>
```

When JSP is submitted following is getting passed to Spring
INFO  2014-11-01 22:21:32,342 com.recipe.mvc.RecipeController - From JSP [Recipe [id=null, name=sandwich]

Why id is not getting passed here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `<sf:hidden path="id" />` value in your `<sf:form>`.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.hidden